# pygame.error: font not initialized how to fix?

Tags: python, pygame

So I am having this error pygame.error: font not initialized and I have tired to fix by indenting it, unidentified it, changing the font and other stuff but it still wont work Its at my STARTMENUE. I have
also tried using another font thinking that was the problem but's not.

were I am having my problem

```
largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansblod.ttf',115)
```

My full code

```
import pygame

#set screen
window = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))

#set Name
pygame.display.set_caption("Noob")


class Player:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.speed = 0
        self.isJump = False
        self.JumpCount = 10
        self.fall = 0
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.topleft = (self.x,self.y)

class Floor:
    def __init__ (self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)


class Coin():
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        self.draw.rect(self.color,self.rect)
    


white = (255,255,255)

green = (0,200,0)

red = (255,0,0)

drakred = (200,0,0)

darkgreen = (0,200,0)

black = (0,0,0)
 
player1 = Player(50,400,40,40,white)

coin = Coin(100,300,30,30,red)

floor1 = Floor(0,400,600,30,green)



fps = (30)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

###########################################
#START MENUE
def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac,action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    #print(click)
    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(window, ac,(x,y,w,h))

        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            action()         
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(window, ic,(x,y,w,h))

    smallText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",20)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
    textRect.center = ( (x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)) )
    window.blit(textSurf, textRect)

def quitgame():
    pygame.quit()
    
def game_intro():
    

    intro = True

    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            #print(event)
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        
        window.fill((255,255,255))
        largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansblod.ttf',115)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Jump", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((500/2),(500/2))
        window.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        button("GO!",100,350,100,50,green,darkgreen,main_loop)
        button("Quit!",300,350,100,50,orange,darkred,quitgame)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)

###############################################



def main_loop():
    def redrawwindow():
        window.fill((0,0,0))

            
        player1.draw()
        coin1.draw()
        floor1.draw()


        window.blit(text,textRect)

        font = pygame.font.Font("freesansblod.ttf",30)
        score = 0
        text = ("Coin"+str(score),True,(255,255,255))
        textRect = text.get_rect()
        textRect.center = ((100,40))

        run = True
        while run:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT():
                    run = False

            for Coin in coin1:
                for coin1 in range(len(coin)-1-1-1):
                    if player1.rect.colliderect(coin1[one].rect):
                        del coin1[one]
                        score += 1
                        text = pygame.font.Font("blod.ttf",30)
                        textRect.center ((100,40))
                            
                        
                        



            key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
                    
            if key[pygame.K_a]:
                player1.x -= player1.speed

            if key[pygame.K_d]:
                player1.x += player1.speed

            if key[pygame.K_w]:
                player1.y -= player1.speed
            if key[pygame.K_s]:
                player1.y += player1.speed



        redrawwindow()
        pygame.display.update()
    pygame.quit()
game_intro()
main_loop()
```

Comment: "freesansb**lo**d" or "freesansb**ol**d" ?  (looks like a typo, of course you font could be named Free Sans Blod!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding    pygame.font.init() right below where you import pygame.